# How to remove jquery-1.7.min.js

Tags: jquery

My project uses `jquery-1.7.min.js`. How can i replace the code using `jquery-1.7.min.js.` for example what can i do with the following code?

```
$(this._divArrContextMenuItem[i]).bind("mouseover", oContextMenuItem, 
                                       AGContextMenuMouseManager.mouseOverHandler);
$(this._divArrContextMenuItem[i]).bind("mouseout", oContextMenuItem,
                                       AGContextMenuMouseManager.mouseOutHandler);
```

Comment: you can consolidate them with hover, i believe

Answer (score 1):

If you no longer want to use jQuery, you can just use standard Javascript event listeners.

Assuming `this._divArrContextMenuItem[i]` is a DOM element:

```
 this._divArrContextMenuItem[i].addEventListener('mouseover', AGContextMenuMouseManager.mouseOverHandler);

 this._divArrContextMenuItem[i].addEventListener('mouseout', AGContextMenuMouseManager.mouseOutHandler);
```